# problem while finding iphone memory programmatically

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am facing a strange problem with my iphone. It shows **available memory as 278 Mb from settings and also in the itunes** . But when I find it programmatically like this

```
NSDictionary *fileSystemAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:&error];
double availableSpace = [[fileSystemAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] floatValue];
```

**I am getting it as 458.0 Mb**. Can any one help me out why I'm having so much difference between both the values ?? As both the values should be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone uses a solid state drive, which doubles as it's own system RAM. So it keeps a percentage of the total drive for use at runtime.

Go with the number iTunes is telling you, because otherwise there could be some critical system errors.

Comment: Yeah.. when in doubt, go with the low number! :D

Comment: yeah i did the same thing thanks guys :) . Kept a offset of 500 mb.